# Delete and Reinitialize pertained BERT weights / parameters

Tags: nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I tried to fine-tune BERT for a classification downstream task.

Now I loaded the model again and I run into the following warning:

Some weights of the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased were not used when initializing BertModel: ['cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.weight', 'cls.predictions.bias', 'cls.seq_relationship.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias', 'cls.predictions.decoder.weight']

- This IS expected if you are initializing BertModel from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing BertModel from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJZVc.png)

I already deleted and reinstalled transformers==4.6.0 but nothing helped.
I thought maybe through the parameter "force_download=True" it might get the original weights back but nothing helped.

Shall I continue and ignore the warning? Is there a way to delete the model checkpoints such when the model is downloaded the weights are fixed again?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're fine-tuning a model for a downstream task this warning can be ignored. The idea is that the `[CLS]` token weights from the pretrained model aren't going to be useful for downstream tasks and need to be fine-tuned.

Huggingface randomly initializes them because you're using `bert-base-cased` which is a `BertForPretraing` model and you're created a `BertModel` from it. The warning is to ensure that you understand the difference of directly using the pretrained model directly or if you're planning on finetuning them for a different task.

On that note if you plan working on a classification task I'd recommend using their `BertForSequenceClassification` class instead.

TL;DR you can ignore it as long as you're finetuning.

Answer (score 0):

I have kind of "solved" the problem or at least I found a solution:

- One Conda environment for downstream task classification: `conda install -c conda-forge transformers`
- One Conda environment for just getting the embeddings: `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 transformers`